# Управляемая vs неуправляемая память

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Возможно, это глупый вопрос. Читая книгу Рихтера CLR via C#, в главе 14 наткнулся на неуправляемую память. Ну так вот, чем отличается ***управляемая*** и ***неуправляемая*** память?

Comment: ну так полистайте дальше до главы про сборщик мусора, там где то должно быть написано

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Программа в .NET имеет свой менеджер памяти, который занимается автоматическим выделением памяти под объекты и очисткой памяти после объектов (сборка мусора). 
Это значит что программист не заботится о выделении памяти и ее очистке. 
Такой тип памяти называется управляемой памятью. И все объекты, которые вы создаете в .NET располагаются в управляемой памяти. Это все встроенные типы: `int, string, double, Array, List<>` и т.п. Все они - управляемые объекты и располагаются в управляемой памяти.

Однако, программа работает не только с управляемыми объектами. Часть объектов связана с операционной и файловой системами, с WinAPI, с драйверами, с видеокартой, с сетью и т.д. Понятно, что все эти внешние ресурсы никак не связаны с менеджером памяти .NET и потому на них не распространяется автоматическое распределение памяти. Такая память и такие объекты называются неуправляемыми.

Answer (score 5):

Рихтер, вроде, все подробно объясняет.

Управляемая память находится под контролем CLR и при необходимости(когда в стеке закончилось место под объекты) вызывается сборщик мусора, который удаляет объекты на которых нету корневых ссылок, выполняет дефрагментацию.

Неуправляемая память же целиком в руках программист и он хозяин процесса выделения/освобождения памяти.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее подразумевается неуправляемая и управляемая модели памяти. *Управляемая* отличается от первой тем, что там с объектами работает GC, который память очищает, дефрагментирует, поддерживает актуальность ссылок на лету. Расположение объекта в памяти в каждый момент времени не детерменированно. Ее состояние **управляется извне**.

В *неуправляемой* модели ничего такого нет - память выделяется и очищается по требованию **самой программы**.

Comment: Ну, сборщик мусора — тоже часть программы, поэтому, формально говоря, и управляемая память очищается по требованию самой программы.

Comment: @VladD, если под _программой_ понимать процесс в ОС, то это так. Сборщик мусора - это часть рантайма, а в той _программе_, которая управляет бизнес-логикой, которую пишет программист, а SDK собирает в сборку, нет кода GC и явных системных вызовов (которые были бы в нативном коде).